# Initializing Appdelegate Object in xcode 8

Tags: objective-c, warnings, appdelegate, xcode8

Initialising appdelegate object in xcode 8 throwing warnings. Is anything wrong in the following syntax

```
AppDelegate *del=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

Comment: What warning is it throwing? Is `AppDelegate` your own `UIAppDelegate` subclass? Then `AppDelegate *del= (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];` may fix this, but it may break things if it's not an `AppDelegate` object.

Answer (score 0):

I give you another option to use **Appdelegate** Object and decalre it in **appdelegate.h** file like this

```
#define theAppDelegate \
((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)
```

HOPE This works fine